# Salesforce Federated single sign on with AD

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

I need to know there is a mechanism if the AD is down and when user login to salesforce with only sso (When mydomain settings, selected only single sign on) , what is the way to log in.

Thanks,
Prasad.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Single_Sign-On_with_SAML_on_Force.com) in the developer community site lists some best practices. Amongst which are:

1. Do not SSO enable administrators
2. Come up with a failover strategy

Reading into this, I would say that one possible strategy is to disable SSO for users in case of a prolonged IDP outage, then reenabling when the outage is done. But there is nothing special that Salesforce does for you in this instance. Just like with any SSO strategy, with any software product, you will need to plan for how your organization addresses this.

Comment: Hi Peter,thanks for your answer.. please let me know how to not enable SSO for administrators.